# Standard derivative of $\cos^2(5x+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$\text{Find }\,\dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(\cos^2(5x+1)\Big).$$

I have tried using the rules outlined in my standard derivatives notes but I've failed to find the point of application.

Comment: $cos^2(5x+1)=[cos(5x+1)]^2$ Does it help to write it like this?

Comment: You need the power rule, then the chain-rule twice here.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} & = \dfrac{d \cos^2(5x+1)}{dx}\\
               & = 2\cos(5x+1) \dfrac{d \cos(5x+1)}{dx}\\ 
               & = 2\cos(5x+1)(-\sin(5x+1))\dfrac{d(5x+1)}{dx}\\ 
               & = -2\cos(5x+1)\sin(5x+1) \cdot 5\\
               & = -10\cos(5x+1)\sin(5x+1)\\ 
               & = -5\sin(10x+2)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$y = \cos^2(5x+1)=\Big(\cos(5x+1)\Big)^2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2(\cos(5x+1))\cdot (-\sin(5x+1)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(5x+1)$$

$$=-10\cos(5x+1) \sin (5x+1)$$
We applied the power-rule first, then used the chain-rule, twice.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use $$2y = 2\cos^2(5x+1) = \cos(10x + 2)  + 1$$ so that $$2\frac{dy}{dx} = -10\sin(10x+2)\to \frac{dy}{dx} = -5\sin(10x+2) $$